# How to enter degree celsius in java label box?

Tags: java, netbeans, label, hex

I am having troble  entering the symbol for degree celsuis in a java label box.

[image: Degree Celsius]

I referred to a book and got the following instructions for entering the degree symbol:

> 1. Make sure that numlock is ON
> 2. Then Pressing Alt type 0186

But the Problem is that when I press numlock on my laptop (it is also my F11 key) it opens the window for Building main project.

Secondly when I press Alt and type 0186 appears in the label.

Can you describe what this number (0186) is and also why we can't simply use 186 instead of 0186.

Comment: I dont want the  idea of using two lable box. One for a small size o and other for a big C.

Comment: Hum, stupid question, but do you have a numpad on your laptop? Strange that the numlock key and the F11 key are the same...

Comment: Check if, in your laptop, you have to press [Fn]+[F11] in order to emulate the key [NumLock]. Maybe you are just pressing [F11] and it's been interpreted as just [F11].

Comment: Also, as  sp00m pointed out: which keys do you press to write the number 0186? They MUST be the ones in the numpad. NOT the keys with the horizontal layout. In my laptop, they are normal letter keys, with a blue label showing the number. I mean, theres a key labeled with a white 'J' and a blue '1'. To emulate the key [1] from a numpad, I press [Fn]+[J].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, some background: Each font has between about 26 to 20'000 different "glyphs" ("a" is the glyph for "lower case A", i.e. a shape which you think means something). [The Unicode standard](http://unicode.org/charts/) lists all of them.

Since there are many more glyphs than keys on your keyboard, a solution had to be found. That solution was <kbd>Alt</kbd> + character code. See here for a list: [Windows Alt Key Codes](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/accents/codealt.html). It also contains [detailed instructions](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/accents/codealt.html#using) how to enter the codes.

The code for `°` is `0176`, by the way, not 0186.

To enable num lock on your laptop (which has even less keys than the standard 105 keys keyboard), you need to press the "Function" key (usually a blue F somewhere in the lower left corner) plus <kbd>F11</kbd>

Lastly, why `0176` rather than `176`. The `0` actually tells Windows that you're about to enter an Alt code. This is necessary since Alt usually controls the UI (activate controls and menus via their shortcut).

Comment: That's true: code `0176` is for degree glyph `°` (celsius, farenheit, or circle's degrees).
Code `0186`, which showns really similar: `º` is the "masculine ordinal" glyph. In some fonts it's exactly the same as the degree glyph, in others, it has a small line below.

Note: it's the masculine ordinal sign in some languages other than English. In Spanish's `1º` would be English's `1st`.

Comment: @R41nB0wM47r1z: The code works; are you on Windows? Is the NumLock LED glowing?

Comment: Does your laptop even have numeric keys?

Answer (score 2):

Just copy and paste it from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_symbol).

Alternately, you could use the HTML character code `&deg;` if you're using it in a HTML context, for example, in web development.

Comment: +1 for copying from the web. -1 for `&deg;` since that won't work in a Swing UI.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Didn't realise that the question was about Swing UI. Edited my answer. I do know that `&deg;` wouldn't work in anything non-HTML.

Answer (score 1):

What IDE are you using? If it supports other means of entering the symbol that may prove easier, such as copying and pasting the symbol from somewhere ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_symbol), maybe?).

Does your keyboard have a <kbd>function</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd> key that you can press to enable your <kbd>F11</kbd> key to work as the <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> key? There should be some sort of status LED to show that <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> has been enabled successfully. When you type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+0176 you will have to use the numpad (On some laptops these can overlap the main QWERTY region of the keyboard, normally on the right hand side, starting at <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> or thereabouts). The number has to have all 4 digits, as it is a Unicode code-point.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is nothing in Java that prevents special characters from being entered into text fields.I am able to enter the degree symbol º in JTextField on my PC and my laptop.
I'm not sure that your error is related to Java at all - it sounds like a key conflict on your laptop where your numlock key is also F11. You should not need to hold numlock down for this operation. Try turning num lock on **outside of netbeans** and then try entering the number.

Likewise, if you are running your program outside of netbeans, (you can double-click the jar file in the dist folder) then this F11/numlock conflict problem should go away.

**Why does 0186 mean the degree symbol?**

Character 186 is part of the extended [ASCII chart](http://www.ascii-code.com/). It is one of those characters that almost every Font supports, but you cannot type it on the keyboard because there is no key for it. Windows gives us a convenient way of entering extended ASCII characters: Hold down alt, type the ASCII code in the number pad and then the character appears.

Very few average users know this trick. When they want to enter a degree symbol. When a typical user wants to enter a degree symbol, the user looks for a special character menu function like we find in MS Word or Open Office Writer. Those familiar with HTML will know that you can enter special character in a web page by escaping the code: º  So if your character needs the user to enter this symbol, you can give the user a button to append it to the text field.

When I've written programs where the output is in degrees, I never asked the user to enter the symbol. I just appended the correct symbol to the output so it would display nicely. For instance:

```
String degree = "" + (char)186;

String answer = celsiusToFaren(userInputC) + degree;
```